# iOS Storyboards - Re-use UIViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've got the following structure setup in my Storyboard.

[image]

I've got a TabViewController (circled in red) that shows a UIViewController via one of its tabs by doing a push (circled in blue).

I want to re-use that UIViewController from the TabViewController. I'd like to 'push' it but I don't really have a navigation controller so I may end up displaying it as a modal.

However, I'm not sure how to handle navigation back to the TabViewController since in this case there's no navigation bar. Any suggestions on the best way to handle this?

**EDIT**

Is there a way to insert a Navigation controller when its displayed directly from the TabViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancel button whose action is `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: Does this work when its displayed from a segue? How do I show a navigation bar in one case (modal) and not the other (push)?

Comment: It works in modal segue. The bar will be shown by navigation controller if it exists, but it may be a good idea to display a navbar in both cases. I think the left button of navbar will be replaced by the back button whenever navcontroller exists, so try putting it there. If storyboard starts to look messy, you should do one type (modal/push) in code.

Comment: In the case of the Nav controller... that works now with an auto back button. The problem I'm trying to solve is how to get a nav bar in there when it's displayed as a modal (but not show double-nav's when it's pushed).

Comment: One approach would be to add navbar in code wherever it does not exist. Also, did you check that a manually added to storyboard VC navbar will lead to double? Maybe it just works :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you put your view hierarchy like this:

**UITabBarController** -> **UINavigationController** -> **BlueViewController**

This UINavigationController should be put in the **viewControllers** property of the **UITabBarController** instance. If you do this, you can push and pop as many view controller as you want and you can also hide the navigation bar if needed.

Comment: Doesn't that just make it another tab? It's not my intent to make it a tab in this case.

Comment: So I could not understand what exactly you want =/